# what model is this Sennheiser shotgun?

Tags: microphone, sennheiser

I'm having the opportunity to buy by second hand a Sennheiser shotgun, but there is no written the model.
Does anyone recognize it?

[image: shotgun]

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a K6 + ME 66 Sennheiser system.
https://en-us.sennheiser.com/k6-modular-microphone-system-omni-directional-cardioid-short-gun-long-gun

Comment: thanks, I really think it's k6+ me 66!